# Zurb Foundation: how to change number of columns at a breakpoint?

Tags: css, sass, css-float, row, zurb-foundation

I'd like to build a markup that behaves like so:

**Portrait**

```
<element-1><element-2>
<element-3><element-4>
<element-5><element-6>
```

**Landscape**

```
<element-1><element-2><element-3>
<element-4><element-5><element-6>
```

In my SASS main file I added new html classes using the Zurb Foundation mixins:

```
// Foundation
@import "../bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/grid";

// new grid classes
$small-only-and-landscape: "#{$screen} and (max-width: #{upper-bound($small-range)}) and (orientation: landscape)";
$small-only-and-portrait: "#{$screen} and (max-width: #{upper-bound($small-range)}) and (orientation: portrait)";

@media #{$small-only-and-landscape} {
    @include grid-html-classes($size:small-landscape);
}

@media #{$small-only-and-portrait} {
    @include grid-html-classes($size:small-portrait);
}
```

Somewhere in my index.html there's something like that:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-landscape-4 small-portrait-6 columns">
        <a href="pictures.html">Bilder</a>
    </div>
    <div class="small-landscape-4 small-portrait-6 columns">
        <a href="#">Freunde</a>
    </div>
    <div class="small-landscape-4 small-portrait-6 columns">
        <a href="#">Videos</a>
    </div>
    <div class="small-landscape-4 small-portrait-6 columns">
        <a href="#">Basteln</a>
    </div>
    <div class="small-landscape-4 small-portrait-6 columns">
        <a href="#">Spiele</a>
    </div>
    <div class="small-landscape-4 small-portrait-6 columns">
        <a href="#">Audio</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**This works fine. Now here's my question:**
As you can see, I'm using an "overfull" `.row`, floating its elements in a way they rearrange into a "two-column-grid" or a "three-column-grid". I feel, this is a dirty trick.

Is there a way to solve my problem in a clean way? Via `.push-#`, `.pull-#` or `.offset-#`?

Thank you so much in advance!

Niels

Comment: You have to more clear with foundation [grid docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html)

Comment: I did. But all their examples show how to change the size of columns from breakpoint to breakpoint not the number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

I found the [answer](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block_grid.html) one tab further on the Zurb foundation docs.